# Authentication for an external Sharepoint Web Part Page (SSO)

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, web-parts, single-sign-on

An external hosted app can take the username and password in the querystring and auto login the user. How do I get these details from Sharepoint?

I know you can use `SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;` if the application is hosted locally however it isn't.

How can we achieve single sign on from Sharepoint to the external 3rd party software?

Comment: Anyone any idea? I would have thought SSO with an external app was common stuff?